# Writing a GPU Bitcoin mining client (learning purposes)

Tags: mining-pools, api, gpu-mining, mining-software, learning

I want to write a basic GPU miner from scratch for learning purposes. 
By "from scratch" I don't mean that I am unwilling to use libraries but I want it to be similar to real GPU mining software, and I want to *learn in-depth* from this.

More specifically:

1. I want to write a functional GPU mining software.
2. It should mine with a pool (I was thinking a pool that uses stratum but other protocols are fine).
3. It should be similar in efficiency to GPU mining software currently in use. (This isn't required but I would like to learn how it is done in "real life")

I know python and java, and I can learn C if required. I know how Bitcoin mining works in general, but don't know the details of GPU mining algorithms communication protocols etc.

I was wondering where I should start. Where can I find libraries and general information about this process? Is this even possible or is it too difficult for one person?
I know I can use google but I don't know where to start.

Comment: You should take a look at poclbm.

Comment: Did you look at existing implementations on github?

Comment: Start by looking at the source code for the GPU miner that's most like the one you plan to make.